Power BI - Field Parameter value
I have created a field parameter, i cannot manage to have a measure created in order to return the values got by the slicer.

I need to calculate the difference between a static value and the field parameter value. when i try to return the measure, it says that as the value is a TEXT, it is not working.
I tried to create a column searching for the "values" (table) field, but i did not manage to do it.
Is there any option to create a measure to return the value of the selected?

Can you share more data ?

Sure, what i mean is:
The field parameter works well, if i choose the slicer, it retreives the correct value.
But what i need, is to use that value for other calculations, like doing the difference between that (dynamic value returned by the slicer) and another value.
Ex:
SlicerValue1(1000) - 500 = 500
SlicerValue2(200) - 500 = -300
The end result is that i cannot use the dax SELECTEDVALUE as it returns a TEXT and not a number. And i'm not managing to use a measure .

Can you share your file/model?
